# fopen() failure on external server

Tags: php, content-management-system, fopen

I had created this CMS system which uses a mySQL database and creates a file on the server.

The database side works as intended, but the creation of the file not so well.

Everything works perfectly on my localhost but the creation of the file is not working right on the external WWW server. 
I had created a basic script to test the functionality of fopen() on the server. That had worked correctly, but for the real script it doesn't work.

This is the code in the real script:

```
if(fopen(strtolower("../News/" . $titleURL . ".php"), "w+")){
    $createdPage = fopen(strtolower("../News/" . $titleURL . ".php"), "w+");
    echo "page created";
}else{
    echo "creation failed";
}
```

When this page is run, I get creation failed.

This code runs fine on the localhost, but why not on the external site?

EDIT:

My hosting service does not block fopen()

Comment: Do you have file write permissions on your webserver?

Comment: I do, I have tested this with a test basic script. It just isn't working for this particular file.

Comment: I doubt doing 2 fopens to the same file one straight after the other is a good idea, especially as you don't obtain a handle in the first fopen and clean up by fcloseing afterward.

Comment: Is it possible that your host blocks `fopen` command ?

Comment: Please do this: 1.) remove your whole "if else" statement and replace it with: fopen(strtolower("../News/" . $titleURL . ".php"), "w+")
This will generate an error to the PHP error_log, please update your question to include that error.

Answer (score 0):

IT is very likely that the configuration for your host server (and/or the target server) does not allow any file manipulation on/by a foreign server.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved. I had just cleaned up the code a bit, cleaning up a lot of concatenating URLs. It appears the server did not appreciate me concatenating file locations. Everything is working fine.